# Apache2 mod_rewrite - how to add trailing slash to only one subdirectory

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, apache2

I'm using Apache 2.2 with two servers:

- **Development**: localhost/project/public
- **Production**: www.example.com

I have an existing rewrite rule for clean urls (to remove 'index.php' from the url).

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have one special route that *only* works if a trailing slash is present:

- **special route (development)**: localhost/public/documentation/
- **special route (production)**: www.example.com/documentation/

How do I add a rewrite rule to my existing .htaccess to always add a trailing slash, but only for the documentation route?

Comment: Is _/index.php/`this`_ page really exist and what do you want to do? Please explain more..

Comment: @Servant example.com/index.php is a Laravel PHP application. example.com/documentation/index.html is a static html website. But I decided to 'tunnel' it through PHP as a Laravel route, in order to enforce access controls. However, the relative CSS/JS links in the static website only work if there is a trailing slash on the documentation url, hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add another `RewriteRule` that matches only against `/documentation` i.e. without a trailing slash. The first rule adds the trailing slash and then your existing rule adds the `index.php`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(documentation)$ $1/ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

If you would like the browser's address bar to also reflect the trailing slash change the rule to

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(documentation)$ $1/ [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks. Yes I do need the address bar to reflect the trailing slash. But your second example seems to redirect to http://localhost/var/www/project/public/documentation/ instead of http://localhost/project/public/documentation/ ... any ideas?

Comment: With your revised second code snippet, this redirects to http://localhost/documentation/ not http://localhost/var/www/vessel-monitoring-1/public/documentation/ as required on the development server. Is there one rule I can use for both the development and production servers?

Comment: This can be accommodated but with a different base dir on development `RewriteBase /project/public/`. Since, the deployment directories are different the `.htaccess` cannot be 100% portable.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add these directives first once per *.htaccess* file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
```

And then you can try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(documentation)$ /$1/ [R,NC,L]
```

Or this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.+)/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^/?(documentation)/(.+)$ /$1/$2/ [R,NC,L]
```

I'm confused about your question..